# Are there performance issues with virtual can interfaces on linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, virtual, can-bus

On a Linux System we can create virtual CAN interfaces -> vcan0 ... normaly they are used for testing purposes. My question is the following: Can I use a virtual CAN interface for transmitting data from one application to another application on the same linux system? I know that it is possible but are there performance concerns?

The same question also about virtual ethernet sockets.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "security" isn't a checkbox on something marketing pamphlet. without ANY knowledge of your security requirements, operating environment, etc... it is pretty much impossible to comment properly on anything involving "security".

Comment: anybody experience with vcan?